# How does brain activity change when focusing on something within peripheral vision, as opposed to the fovea?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, vision, eyes

Normally when looking around, we mentally focus on what we see within our fovea, as that is where we have the greatest visual acuity. However, it is still possible to focus (both physically with the eyes and mentally with our attention) on an object in our peripheral vision.

Can we detect any changes in brain activity when this happens? Do different regions of the visual cortex or prefrontal cortex become more active?

Comment: What have you already read on the topic? The best Biology.SE questions are questions where you can support your question with a basis in something you've read. In other words, show the research you've done to come to this question. Every StackExchange site has some version of this requirement.

Comment: This may work better on [psychology.se], with the eyes and CNS being so intimately connected and the question being regarding brain activity. You'd need to show your background reading there also.

Comment: That makes me think of the test where frowning faces are placed on a monitor in peripheral vision, amidst smiling faces, smilies... The brain cannot consciously see and register them, and the subconscious brain is wired to turn the eyes towards any frowning face is peripheral vision, as a primitive defence system that exists in the cortex, which operates faster than conscious thought.

Comment: I know for sure that there has been extensive research on this, particularly on experiments with monkeys --with functional Magnetic Resonance Imaging (fMRI) or Electroencephalography (EEG). Just do a short research on the web and you will see the avalanche. Sensory visual attention is one of the most investigated areas.